# How to pass "id_token" as responseType instead of "code" in AppAuth iOS to get the token

Tags: ios, authentication, appauth

I am using AppAuth library for authentication and retrieve token, as response_type "id_token", but the library gives the following error:

> The response_type "id_token" isn't supported. AppAuth only supports the "code" response_type.'

i want to use "id_token" as response_type not "code", but am not getting any way out.

Comment: https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS/blob/master/Source/OIDAuthorizationRequest.m#L117 seems like you need to use `code id_token` as response type.

Comment: I tried this, but it doesnt work.